# DNN and FCK editor upload images

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

In dnn I want to set the path for the person logged in when they use the editor - currently I cant let people upload threir own photos becasue to amny people can see to many other peoples pics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally if you are looking to do this, I would go the route of switching to the Telerik RadEditor.  it has some better extension points that can allow you to accomplish this desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that myself, but have a look [here](http://rizwanshah.blogspot.com/2009/05/upload-user-specific-images-in-fck.html) and [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/127/threadid/158276/scope/posts/Default.aspx). The same solution is described in both places.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have been down that path - sorry 

This does not work above 4.5 (I think) but only in versions lower than that.